# How to set height of background color of UIlabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to limit height of background color of a UIlabel.

Is it possible ?

```
mainLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.090, green: 0.090, blue: 0.090, alpha: 0.8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible for a UILabel.

What I'd recommend doing would be creating a container view that matches the height of your UILabel exactly. Add in your UILabel as a subview of this container view, then simply add a UIView as a subview behind the label, and set it's height to what you'd like. This will give you the effect you're looking for.